# How to convert Ajax data response to string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, regex

**Original version:**

```
<div>
    <p>
        <span>text</span>
    </p>
<div>
```

**RegExp:**

```
$.get('/some.html', function(data) {
    alert(data.replace(/<p.*p>/gi, ''));
});
```

**After RegExp:**

```
<div>
    <>
        <span>text</span>
    </>
<div>
```

**What do I need to get:**

```
<div>

<div>
```

Comment: I don't think that the title of this question reflects what the question is about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript has no  dotall mode so your `.` does not match newline characters.

but you can try this

```
$.get('/some.html', function(data) {
    alert(data.replace(/<p[\S\s]*?p>/gi, ''));
});
```

`[\S\s]` means match any non whitespace (`\S`) or any whitespace (`\s`) character. the newline characters are included in the whitespace characters.

The `*?` is a non greedy match, means it matches as less as possible.

**As soon as your tags are nested, you will run into problems when using regular expressions.** You have to be aware of that. Probably the solution from @fearofawhackplanet is the better choice.

Comment: So, i want to parse ajax response as string like this: 
http://jsfiddle.net/DgejB/

Answer (score 2):

If you want to work with the returned html, then you shouldn't be doing that through regex.

I'm not completely sure I understand your question, but it looks like you are trying to remove the `<p>` elements from the result? You can work with the returned html with jQuery, something like

```
$(data).remove('p');
```

Answer (score 0):

if i got you correctly then you need something like this...but it will make all div in your page as a blank div

```
 $('div').html('');
```

if you want remove specific div then give an id to that div and then do it like this..

```
$(data).find('#divID').html(' ');
```

Comment: Think he wants to change it and then display the content, but displaying and then changing will also achieve what is intended right.

Comment: I need to convert an ajax data to string and use it as usual string to parse

Comment: @Balanivash-just look at his last point- he just want a div having no innerHTML.. as he pointed out in his question

Comment: @Algorithm - ajaxcall returns string itself

Answer (score 0):

Javascript regexp don't match \n with ".". And you specified //g flag. in normaly, use [\s\S] in javascript.

```
alert(data.replace(/<p[\s\S]*?p>/i, ''));
```

Comment: and you should specify "?" for minimum match. :)